# How to refresh page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am new to flutter development. I wanted to achieve android `onResume()` functionality
in flutter. I was handling that using `then()` like this

```
Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PageTwo()))
    .then((value) {
    refresh();
});
```

This is working fine If i am coming back from `PageTwo` to `PageOne`.

I am going to pageThree `PageOne->pageTwo using Push()` and `pageTwo->PageThree using PushReplacement()`. When i `pop()` pageThree pageOne is not refreshing.

Answer (score -1):

Call the same `then()` when you call `pushReplacement()` to `PageThree`

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PageThree()))
.then((_) => refresh());
```

Comment: refresh method is not available on PageTwo class

Comment: In that case, you may need to subscribe a Route Observer on the root widget to call `refresh()` whenever the current top route is `PageOne`. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html